# Getting unique and overlapping counts for values in R dataframes

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, unique

I have this large data frame with records that have repeated IDs that are in multiple groups like below:

```
ID   GROUP               
--   ------
1    GROUPA                      
1    GROUPB                      
3    GROUPA                      
3    GROUPC                      
3    GROUPC                      
2    GROUPB
```

How is it possible to get the count for unique records in each group, as well as how many IDs are overlapped between groups? like:

```
#         Unique To Group    Overlap with others     Uniques not in group
------    ---------------    -------------------     -------------------
GROUPA          1                    2                     1
GROUPB          1                    1                     2
GROUPC          1                    1                     2
```

So overlap is by the ID:

- if ID is unique to GROUP - then unique to Group
- if ID is repeated in other groups then it is an overlap
- if ID is not present in group but present in others - it is unique not in group

Currently I am thinking of doing this in a loop like:

```
GROUPA = df[which(df$Group == 'A'), ]
for (id in df$id) {
  if is.element(id, GROUPA):
    GroupACount <- GroupACount+1
etc
```

Not sure how to do the overlap though. But is there a better way maybe with apply and %in%?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The question is not very clear. I can't see how overlap is counted

Comment: @sayandasgupta - sorry, just added clarification.

Comment: Does your desired output represents the data that you provided?

Comment: For example Uniques not in group for group A is 2 as calculated from the given data right ?

Comment: @DavidArenburg - just changed, they are now

Comment: @sayandasgupta just one actually (ID=2), because 3 is in both A and C.

Comment: For future questions, always provide a desired output that corresponds to the data provided, otherwise you just wasting everyones time

Comment: @DavidArenburg - sorry, still new to this.

Comment: @Kash I still do not understand how for Group A I have 0 Unique To Group.

Comment: In your data set only `ID == 2` is unique to `GROUPB` other groups don't have IDs that unique only for them. So your desired output doesn't make sense to me again

Comment: @DavidArenburg The IDs are unique to the record but the records are repeated as they often belong to multiple groups. Oh and the output is the counts not the actual IDs.

Comment: I have to admit that I still don't understand your desired output, so I'll let someone who does to help you with this question

Comment: I neither understand how is the output constructed. If you want No uniques _inside_ each group, then "A" and "B" should have 2 (because 2 IDs appear _once_ in each group), while "C" should have 1 (ID 3 appears twice), shouldn't it? If you want No uniques _to_ each group, then "A" and "C" should have 0 and "B" should have 1? In "unique_not", do you count the IDs that exist everywhere but in a specific group? Also, I don't get "overlaps" either. Could you explain, step by step, how one row from your output is constructed? Sorry if I'm missing something, but I, really, don't get what's going on.

Comment: @alexis_laz Sorry I don't know how to make it more clear but perhaps jogal's answer will allow you to better understand it.

Comment: @Kash are you saying then, that the answer by jogal provides the desired output for the sample data he provided?

Comment: @beginneR yes that's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the spirit of providing a quick and dirty answer that's still useful to you, here's an imperfect solution using a for() loop. Perhaps someone else can improve it by vectorising it.

```
#slight expansion of your sample data
> d <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3), group = c("A", "B", "A", "C", "C", "B", "D", "E", "E"))

# create empty storage matrix
> myDF <- matrix(numeric(0), ncol=4)
# for loop
> for(i in unique(d$group)) {
    #get IDs of this group, and IDs of all other groups
    groupIDs <- unique(d[d$group == i,]$id,)
    otherIDs <- unique(d[d$group != i,]$id,)

    #number of unique IDs in group
    test1 <- groupIDs %in% otherIDs
    uniques_in_group <- length(test1[test1 == FALSE])

    #number of IDs overlapping with other groups
    overlaps <- length(test1[test1 == TRUE])

    #number of unique IDs not in group
    test2 <- otherIDs %in% groupIDs
    uniques_not_in_group <- length(test2[test2 == FALSE])

    #build dataframe
    myDF_i <- data.frame(group = i, uniques_in_group, overlaps, uniques_not_in_group)
    myDF <- rbind(myDF, myDF_i)
}

> myDF

#   group uniques_in_group overlaps uniques_not_in_group
# 1     A                0        2                    2
# 2     B                0        2                    2
# 3     C                0        1                    3
# 4     D                1        0                    3
# 5     E                0        2                    2
```

Comment: This is a really good attempt, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `dyplr` solution using the sample data provided by @jogal.

```
require(dplyr)

d %>% mutate(ids = length(unique(id)),
              n = 1:n(),
              countInOthers = sapply(n, function(currentn){sum(ID[group != group[currentn]] == ID[n == currentn])})) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarize(UniqueInGroup = length(unique(id[countInOthers == 0])),
            OverlapWithOthers = length(unique(ID[countInOthers>0])),
            UniquesNotInGroup = ids[1] - UniqueInGroup - OverlapWithOthers)

#  group  UniqueInGroup OverlapWithOthers UniquesNotInGroup
#1     A             0                 2                 2
#2     B             0                 2                 2
#3     C             0                 1                 3
#4     D             1                 0                 3
#5     E             0                 2                 2
```

With the sample data in the question, the result of this would be:

```
#   group UniqueInGroup OverlapWithOthers UniquesNotInGroup
#1 GROUPA             0                 2                 1
#2 GROUPB             1                 1                 1
#3 GROUPC             0                 1                 2
```

Comment: Which inconsistent with the desired result... Which just means that no one understood what the OP wants

Comment: @DavidArenburg you're right! But based on the description (not what is actually shown in the desired output) that was that I thought was meant.

Comment: @beginneR thank you! This also seems to work. Only issue is that it runs a fair amount slower than jogal's answer for my big data set.

Comment: @DavidArenburg - the 'desired result' which I put was mostly to show the concept, I tried to make it as correct as possible but there were a couple of mistakes there.